Is the Doctor's number ever mentioned within "Doctor Who"?
We all know who “the Nth Doctor” is, but is he ever called that within the show?  Does he mention his past versions by number, perhaps in "The N Doctors” episodes?

The first and fifth Doctors discuss their numbers in The Five Doctors:

DOCTOR 1: Yes, evidently. Now, take it steadily, my boy, and let me help you up.
DOCTOR 5: I tried to send a recall signal.
DOCTOR 1: Yes, it doesn't matter. How do you come to be here?
DOCTOR 5: Well, the Tardis was, er. I don't know.
DOCTOR 1: Never mind that.
SUSAN: Is he really?
DOCTOR 1: Me? Yes. Yes, I'm afraid so. Regeneration?
DOCTOR 5: Fourth.
DOCTOR 1: Goodness me! So, there are five of me now! Oh, er, this is Susan.
DOCTOR 5: Yes, I know.
DOCTOR 1: And, er, you two are?
TURLOUGH: Turlough.
TEGAN: And I'm Tegan Jovanka. Who might you be?
DOCTOR 1: I might be any number of things, young lady. As it happens, I am the Doctor. The original, you might say.
TEGAN: But you shouldn't be here at the same time, with him, should you?
DOCTOR 1: Certainly not.
DOCTOR 5: It only happens in the gravest emergencies.
DOCTOR 1: Like now.
DOCTOR 5: Yes, unfortunately.
DOCTOR 1: Now look, young lady. Make yourself useful. This young fellow looks as though he needs some refreshment and I know that Susan and I do, too.
TEGAN: Hang on a minute.
DOCTOR 5: Tegan, Tegan, Tegan. Humour him. You know, I sometimes used to get a little tetchy. Fortunately one mellows with age. Turlough will help.

Note that the fifth Doctor specifies he is the fourth re-generation.

She's awfully put out about being asked to make coffee for someone who was planning to be an flight attendant.

Yes:
In The Time of The Doctor there's this dialogue:

DOCTOR: No, not for ever. I can change twelve times. Thirteen versions of me. Thirteen silly Doctors.
CLARA: Okay, so you're number eleven, so
DOCTOR: Ha. Are we forgetting Captain Grumpy, eh? I didn't call myself the Doctor during the Time War, but it was still a regeneration.
CLARA: Okay, so you're number twelve.


It's happened a few times. Here's a few examples:
Time And The Rani
MEL: But you're completely different. Nothing like you were. Face, height, hair, everything's changed.
DOCTOR: Yes. And I've become more of a fool too, it seems, Mel. Doesn't bode well for my seventh persona, being so completely taken in by the wretched Rani.
The Ood sing Vale Decem to the dying Tenth Doctor.
"The fall of the eleventh"
The Name Of The Doctor
CLARA: But I never saw that one. I saw all of you. Eleven faces, all of them you. You're the eleventh Doctor.
